Why is $\partial A=(\overline{A}\setminus A)\cup (A\setminus \mathring{A})$, where $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$?
My book on analysis is using the following definitions (in $\mathbb{R}^k$):
$$\mathring{A}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^k\mid \exists\, r>0:B(x,r)\subseteq A\}\tag{1}$$
$$\overline{A}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^k\mid \forall \, r>0:B(x,r)\cap A\neq \emptyset\}\tag{2}$$
$$\partial A=\overline{A}\setminus \mathring{A}\tag{3}$$
After the definitions, the author says that $\partial A=\overline{A}\cap \overline{A^\complement}$, which I can prove directly.
Then, the author says that :

Since $\mathring{A}\subseteq A\subseteq \overline{A}$, the boundary $\partial A=\overline{A}\setminus\mathring{A}$ can be produced as
$\partial A=(\overline{A}\setminus A)\cup (A\setminus \mathring{A})\tag{4}$

I do not understand how the latter (4) is reached, or how it can be deduced from $\partial A=\overline{A}\cap \overline{A^\complement}$.

The title is missing $\partial$

$A=B$ can usually be proved by showing $A\subseteq B, A\supseteq B $. As for this question, do both $(\subseteq)$ and $(\supseteq)$ confuse you? And as for $(\supseteq)$, do both two components's ($\supseteq$) confuse you?

Here is the Intuition & Heuristics behind that claim :
Consider $A^\circ \subseteq A \subseteq \overline{A}$
What is the meaning or implication in $A^\circ \subseteq A$ ?
It means there might be certain Points in $A$ which are not in the Interior.
Hence $A \setminus A^\circ$ might give some Boundary Points.
What is the meaning or implication in $A \subseteq \overline{A}$ ?
It means there might be certain Points in $\overline{A}$ which are not in $A$.
Hence $\overline{A} \setminus A$ might give some more Boundary Points.
The Union must account for all Boundary Points :
$\partial A = (\overline{A} \setminus A) \cup (A \setminus A^\circ)$
DIAGRAMMATIC VIEW :
Let $A = \{\ (x,y)\ \ |\ \ 0 \le x \lt 1 \ , \ 0 \le y \lt 1 \ \}$

$A$ contains the Blue lines & the Green Area. $A$ does not contain the Purple lines.
Now $A^\circ$ is the Interior Green Area , not including the Blues lines.
We get the Blue lines with $A \setminus A^\circ$
That is not the Complete Boundary.
We can see that $\overline{A}$ includes everything , the Blue lines & the Green Area & the Purple lines.
We get the Purple lines with $\overline{A} \setminus A$
That too is not the Complete Boundary.
We get the Complete Boundary with the Union.
$\partial A = (\overline{A} \setminus A) \cup (A \setminus A^\circ)$

(1) I might be wrong there , @Arthur , though the Example $A$ I gave requires that Union to get the Complete Boundary. Seems my $A$ has Points in the Interior and on the Boundary. It can be said that , I think , my $A$ has certain Points which are indeed not in the Interior. (2) Oh , maybe you are talking about the more general cases ? We can , of course , make Example $B$ where that Union has Empty Set on the left & Example $C$ where that Union has Empty Set on the right.

(3) Maybe the Objection was over my inaccurate wording ? I have made a few changes , @Arthur , which might make it a little more accurate.

Yes, "there might be" is a lot better.

That was what I was thinking [[ $\subseteq$ indicates either SubSet or Equal ]] though my blind typing made it inaccurate. Nice Catch , @Arthur , thank you !!

Okay, your explanation (the intuition part) makes much sense about how it could have been deduced. I managed to prove it partially, please let me know what you think: Since $A^\circ\subseteq A\subseteq \overline{A}$, it is natural to look at the sets $A_1:=A\setminus A^\circ$ and $A_2:=\overline{A}\setminus A$. We observe that $A\setminus A^\circ\subseteq \overline{A}\setminus A^\circ=\partial A$ and $\overline{A}\setminus A\subseteq \overline{A}\setminus A^\circ=\partial A$, so $A_1\cup A_2\subseteq \partial A$. However, it's harder for me to prove $\supseteq$ part.

To prove $\supseteq$, would it be equivalent to prove that $\partial A\cap A_1^c\subseteq A_2$? If so, we have $\partial A\cap A_1^c\subseteq \overline{A}\cap A^c=A_2$, as desired. But, is there a way to prove it directly without this equivalence technique?

@Mr.MathDoctor  $\partial A\subseteq (\overline{A}\setminus A)\cup (A\setminus A^{\circ})$: Select $x\in\partial A$. Then $x\in \overline{A}$ and $x\notin  A^{\circ}$. Either $x\in A$ or $x\notin A$. If $x\in A$, then $x\in A\setminus A^{\circ}$ since $x\notin  A^{\circ}$. If $x\notin A$, then $x\in \overline{A}\setminus A$ since $x\in \overline{A}$.

@Asigan Nice. May I ask, why you would say "Either $x\in A$ or $x\notin A$" out of blue? Is it because that $x$ is somewhere else in a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so it would mean $x\in A\cup A^c$?

@Mr.MathDoctor One and only one of "$x\in A$" and "$x\notin A$" holds. This can be viewed as an axiom.

Axiom is : Either Statement $P$ is true or Statement $P$ is not true , @Asigan , In other words , Either $P$ is true or $\lnot P$ is true.

Either $x \in A$ is true or $x \in A$ is not true : When $x \in A$ is not true , @Mr.MathDoctor , then that gives $x \not \in A$ is true !

@Prem Yes, and hence I said "can be viewed as an axiom". I think it would confuse the question asker if formal logic axiom is introduced here.

$$\begin{align}
\partial A&=(\overline{A}\setminus A)\cup (A\setminus A^\circ)\\
&=(\overline{A}\cap A') \cup(A\cap(A^\circ)')\\
&\stackrel{*}{=}(\overline{A}\cap A') \cup(A\cap\overline{A'})\\
&\stackrel{DM}{=}((\overline{A}\cup A)\cap(\overline{A}\cup\overline{A'}))\cap((A'\cup A)\cap(A'\cup\overline{A'}))\\
&=(\overline{A}\cap X)\cap(X\cap\overline{A'})\\
&=\overline{A'}\cap\overline{A}
\end{align}$$
$(*)$ $(A^\circ)'=\overline{A'}$
$DM:$ De Morgan's distributive laws
